# RabbitMQ slow receiving speed

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-amqp, messagebroker

I need to create application which should receive data from a data producer and process it. I chose RabbitMQ as a message-broker. My tests show me not the best results:

*Sent - 100 msg;

Produce - 100 msg/s;

Consume - 6 msg/s;*

To solve it I set `listenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.NONE);` 
But I need acknowledge for some queues. And I can't do it in parallel using workers, because the order of messages is important for the data processing.

Is it possible to increase the speed of receiving, having acknowledges?

**Producer:**

```
@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(queueName, false);
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("ip");
    connectionFactory.setUsername("name");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("pswd");
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
    return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
}

@Bean
public FanoutExchange exchange() {
    return new FanoutExchange("exchange-1");
}

@Bean
public Binding binding(){
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue()).to(exchange());
}
```

...

```
rabbitTemplate.setExchange("exchange-1");
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(data);
```

**Consumer:**

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("ip");
    connectionFactory.setUsername("name");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("pswd");
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
}

@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue("queue-1", false);
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    listenerContainer.setQueues(queue());
    listenerContainer.setMessageListener(new Receiver());
    listenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    return listenerContainer;
}
```

...

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    System.out.println("Received message: " + fromBytes(message.getBody()) + " \n Time = " + System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

Tested on instance with 2 vCPU and 4 Gb memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the container's `prefetchCount`, which will greatly improve performance. However, if you reject and requeue a message, ordering will be lost (the requeued message will be behind the prefetched messages).